# How do I correctly Mixin on State?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can create and use simple Mixins but to access setState, mounted, context etc in the mixin's methods I need to pass them to from the State class as parameters.

When I to create a Mixin on a State with some boilerplate code to use it on any statefull widget's State, but I get two errors:

```
error: 
The class '_ProfilePageState' cannot implement both 'State<ProfilePage>' and 'State<StatefulWidget>'
because the type arguments are different.
```

```
error: 
Type parameters could not be inferred for the mixin 'NotificationHandlers'
because no type parameter substitution could be found matching the mixin's supertype constraints.
```

The `mixin` definition looks like this:

```dart
mixin NotificationHandlers on State {
  void foo(Map bla) {
    //use setState / context / other properties or State here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should define your `mixin` like this:

```dart
mixin NotificationHandlers<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  // Now you can access all of State's members and use the mixin with State classes.
  // Example:
  @override
  void initState() {
    // ...
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

This ensures that the *generic type* of your `mixin` is the same as the generic type for your `State` class. If you omit the type for `on State`, it is going to default to `StatefulWidget`, but you need to match the exact type, which you can with the syntax I provided.

---

The important syntax is `mixin YourMixin`**`<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T>`**.